# Using discord.js, how would I check if the user has sent a specific message in a specific channel in the last x hours

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot that sends the user a private message if they have not messaged in a specific channel in the last 24 hours - however it does not seem to be executing as expected.

```
  // Check if the user has sent any messages in the last 24 hours
   const lastMessage = message.channel.messages.cache.find(msg => msg.author.id === message.author.id);
  if (!lastMessage || lastMessage.createdTimestamp < Date.now() - 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
    // The user has not sent a message in the last 24 hours
    console.log("Passed first hurdle")
```

I tried doing that but it doesn't seem to work - however if I change the < sign to > it just infinitely deletes a message and sends the user one.

Comment: i'm thinking delete and message sending is not part of this code clip...I would suggest using some console.log() commands, to evaluate lastMessage, and the time calculation

Comment: tried that, its pulling the correct message - the time calculation isnt working tho.

Comment: so now console.log(lastMessage.createdTimestamp) and console.log(Date.now() - 24 * 3600 * 1000) and see the differences....debug from there